# How can I comment an instagram post with Graph API

Tags: php, instagram-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API to make a telegram auto comment bot, but the output says there is an error in the media_id.

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/comments?message=Hi+how+u";

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('access_token' => 'access_token')));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
file_put_contents("res.json", $response);
```

I expect the output be like:

```
{
  "id": "1234567890"
}
```

but it says:

> {"error":{"message":"(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action","type":"OAuthException","code":33,"fbtrace_id":"GQZLb8cu19p"}}

Comment: Does your application have the `instagram_manage_comments` permission approved via App Review and requested as part of the authentication flow?

Comment: Yes it have the instagram_manage_comments, but the authentication flow idk,  what u mean with?

Comment: Put the access token you're using into https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/. See what's in the `Scopes` section of the output. It should include `instagram_manage_comments`.

Comment: Yes it does, also includes manage_pages, pages_show_list, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments, public_profile